# Create new list with insertion based on two lists and one variable in vectorized way

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am looking for a way to vectorize the following algorithm (e.g. with numpy):

```
time = [6.8, 0.6, 2.9, 6.0, 2.2, 4.2, 3.4]
intersections = [True, False, False, True, False, True, False, True]
stop_time = 10
i = 0
time_new = []
i = 0
time_new = []
for j in range(len(intersections)):
    if intersections[j] == True:
        time_new.append(stop_time)
    if j < len(time):
        time_new.append(time[i])
        i += 1
```

`time_new` output is:

```
[10, 6.8, 0.6, 2.9, 10, 6.0, 2.2, 10, 4.2, 3.4, 10]
```

Comment: Were you helped by my answer?

Comment: @ddejohn sorry for confusion but there was an mistake in my code which leave to incorrect `time_new` output. I've fixed it in my question but I am not sure if it is easy to fix in your answer.  Also based on your advice I make `intersections` a boolean list

Comment: What happens if there are more `True`s in `intersections` than there are elements in `time`? Should your algorithm stop, or add `stop_time` for as many times as there are remaining `True`s in `intersections`?

Comment: @ddejohn Good question. Forgot to mention that for any input the following is true: `len(intersections) = len(time)-1`

Comment: I think you meant that the other way around. In your example `len(time) == 7` and `len(intersections) == 8`.

Comment: Anyway, see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.insert`:

```py
idxs, *_ = np.nonzero(intersections)
time_new = np.insert(time, idxs, stop_time)
```

Output:

```py
array([10. ,  6.8,  0.6,  2.9, 10. ,  6. ,  2.2, 10. ,  4.2,  3.4, 10. ])
```